# REST::Client | unable to parse GET response JSON object

Tags: rest, perl

This is the first time i am writing a Perl client to consume a REST service. I am using REST::Client and JSON perl module. The web service returns data in JSON format. The problem is when I try to use from_json or decode_json method on client->responseContent() method, I am getting an error saying

**"malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "HTTP/1.1 200 \r\nCon..."**

The web service is ofcourse a stable one and works fine with other languages REST clients.

After debugging the issue I found that client->responseContent() not only contains the JSON data but also the header information hence from_json is unable to parse it. Below is the snippet of the code:

```
my $url = "/data";
my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->setHost($host);
my $headers = {Accept => 'application/json'};
$client->GET($url, $headers);
my $response = from_json($client->responseContent());
```

Not able to figure out this thing from two days now :-(

Here is the dump of "**$client->{_res}->dump**"

```
Fri Feb 23 09:38:35 2018: HTTP/0.9 200 EOF
Client-Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2018 09:38:35 GMT
Client-Peer: 45.32.84.105:8282
Client-Response-Num: 1

HTTP/1.1 200 \r
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r
Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2018 09:38:33 GMT\r
Connection: close\r
\r
2000\r
[{"REGION":"AP","REMARK":null,"STATUS":"PROD","UPDATED_TIME":null,"UPDATED_BY":null,"ROUTE_ID":1,"ROUTE_ID_VER":20150310,"USER_ROUTE_LOGIC":"|CAPTIVE|","USER_DEST":null,"USER_ORDSIZE_TYPE":null,"MIN_USER_ORDSIZE_VAL":0,"MAX_USER_ORDSIZE_VAL":100,"TAG_775":"|1|","CROSS_CURRENCY":"|Y|N|","TAG_12703":"|PB-CS|","COUNTRY":"|AU|HK|ID|IN|JP|KR|MY|SG|","TAG_12207":...
(+ 423449 more bytes not shown)
```

Even when the transfer encoding is not chunked, I am getting the same issue;

```
Fri Feb 23 10:40:20 2018: HTTP/1.1 200 ^M
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8^M
Content-Length: 1618^M
Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2018 10:40:20 GMT^M
Connection: close^M
^M
{ "data":[ {
  "REGION" : "AP",
  "REMARK" : "",
  "STATUS" : "PROD",
  "UPDATED_TIME" : "",
  "UPDATED_BY" : "",
```

Ultimately, solved using curl command for now (Actual code snippet below):

```
my $command = "curl '$url'";
my $rules = qx/$command/;
```

Comment: What is the result of `$client->{_res}->dump`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the information there. It is all but impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: Okay, at a guess the module isn't intended to cope with chunked response data. I suggest you try `my $json = $client->{_res}->decoded_content` and `my $response = from_json($json)`.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that as well same error. I will see if I can change server code to send data in some other way.

Comment: Thank you @Borodin I have finally given up and my friend suggested me to use curl and it is working fine. Thanks again for your time and effort!

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I couldn't fix it. Is this a public server? Is there a way I can try it for myself, perhaps on an insecure test server? This really needs to be resolved as `REST::Client` is a fairly popular module. By the way, did you check that `LWP` and `REST::Client` were up to date? Can you also show your solution using `curl`?

Comment: Added code snippet using curl (in the question). The web service is not public. However, it is easy to replicate the issue which I did on my home computer as well. Need to check LWP and REST::Client versions. Will give more details on how to replicate the issue. However, you would have to run a sample web service locally using Eclipse (I can share the details). Let me know?

Comment: Yes, please go ahead and post the instructions to enable us to replicate the bug.

Comment: You can run this sample web service. "https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/" . If you have STS (Spring Tool Suite) it would take you minutes to make it running.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue that I am working through. I suspect (Have not verified yet) that the root cause is that the server is not passing the `Encoding-Content` Response Header, therefore `LWP::UserAgent` and `HTTP::Response` are not attempting to return the decoded string. I am going to try to isolate where this decision is being made and see what options are available and request a patch.

[Perl REST::Client - Garbage data in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55837177/perl-restclient-garbage-data-in-response/55866488#55866488)